# Compile from within the OCaml repl

Tags: ocaml

I am using emacs with tuareg mode and I always have the ocaml repl opened inside emacs. I was wondering if there's a way of compiling basic OCaml test files from within the repl so I don't have to run the compilation as a system command.

Comment: It sounds like you may also want the compiled files to be loaded into the top-level? You can either restart the toplevel with the additional arguments, or use `#load "file"` to include it.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there isn't, but you can easily run compilation from within emacs.

If you use the `M-x compile` command (`C-c C-c` using the [tuareg mode](http://tuareg.forge.ocamlcore.org/)), the compilation is run in emacs "compile mode" which is rather nice to work with. In particular, it allows you to jump directly at the erroneous positions in the code in case of compilation error (`M-x goto-next-error` or "C-x `").

With the compile command, you choose the (shell) command to run the compilation. You can invoke the ocaml compiler directly (typically, `ocamlc -c foo.ml`), or use `ocamlfind` to facilitate compilation using external libraries, and even `make` or `ocamlbuild` to automate most of the compilation for you. Typically, if you have a small project using different source files, with a `main.ml` file, `ocamlbuild main.byte` will do the job of building an executable from it.

*Edit* : of course, you could call a system command from within the toplevel, using the `Sys.command` function. But I don't see the point.

Answer (score 1):

By "repl" you mean the "read-eval-print loop", that you may have gotten into for instance running `run-caml` in Emacs.

There is an Emacs command, `compile`, for compiling regardless of what you are doing or the files you are editing. It is usually bound to C-c C-c, but doesn't appear to be in my version of inf-caml. Nevertheless, you may bind it to any convenient sequence (probably not C-c C-c as that is used to interrupt the OCaml toplevel).

You can change the command launched by `compile` (the default is `make -k`). Your commandline should be retained within an Emacs session. If you do not like that it is lost from session to session, write a Makefile to make the default command the correct one. That's the easiest way.